# Questions about "geodesic path" and "arc length of a geodesic path" in the context of GTR and "Lorentzian manifolds"

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-space

I'd like to check my understanding of the notions "[geodesic path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)" and "[arc length of a geodesic path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Generalization_to_.28pseudo-.29Riemannian_manifolds)" in the context of GTR and "[Lorentzian manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold)".

Considering a set of "spacetime events", $\mathcal S$, such that for any two distinct events $A, B \in \mathcal S$ and for any subset $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal S$ it is known

- whether $\mathcal G$ is a "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$", or not, and (if so <sup>1</sup>)
- whether $\mathcal G$ is a "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$ of minimal arc length"<sup>2</sup> (which I'll denote as "$s[~A, B~]$" for reference below), or not,

is it true that

`(1):`
for any two distinct events $A, B \in \mathcal S$ and for any "geodesic path $\mathcal G$ of minimal arc length between $A$ and $B$" (if there is one at all) then for each event $X \in \mathcal G$ which is distinct from events $A$ and $B$ (if there is one at all)

- there is a "geodesic path $\mathcal P$ of minimal arc length between $A$ and $X$" and a "geodesic path $\mathcal Q$ of minimal arc length between $B$ and $X$" which are both subsets of $\mathcal G$, and such that
- the arc length of $\mathcal G$ equals the sum of the arc length of $\mathcal P$ and the arclength of $\mathcal Q$, and either

  - $\mathcal G$, $\mathcal P$, and $\mathcal Q$ are all "null paths", i.e. $s[~A, B~] = s[~A, X~] = s[~B, X~] = 0$, or
  - $\mathcal G$ is not a "null path",
    the ratio of the arc length of $\mathcal P$ to the the arc length of $\mathcal G$ is a positive real number, $\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]} \gt 0$, and
    the ratio of the arc length of $\mathcal Q$ to the the arc length of $\mathcal G$ is a positive real number, $\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]} \gt 0$, too; and

`(2):`
for any two events $J, K \in \mathcal S$ with a **non-null** "geodesic path of minimal arc length between $J$ and $K$"

- either for any three distinct events $A, B, X \in \mathcal S$ with "geodesic paths of minimal arc length between" any two of them, and with $$\frac{s[~A, B~]}{s[~J, K~]} \gt 0, \qquad \frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~J, K~]} \ge 0, \qquad \frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~J, K~]} \ge 0,$$ holds
  $$\scriptsize{1 + \left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^4 + \left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^4 \ge 2~\left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2 + 2~\left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2 + 2~\left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2~\left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2},$$
- or for any three distinct events $A, B, X \in \mathcal S$ with "geodesic paths of minimal arc length between" any two of them, and with $$\frac{s[~A, B~]}{s[~J, K~]} \lt 0, \qquad \frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~J, K~]} \le 0, \qquad \frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~J, K~]} \le 0,$$ holds likewise
  $$\scriptsize{1 + \left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^4 + \left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^4 \ge 2~\left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2 + 2~\left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2 + 2~\left(\frac{s[~A, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2~\left(\frac{s[~B, X~]}{s[~A, B~]}\right)^2}$$

?

**Notes (in response to comments)**

<sup>1</sup>: The fact that a certain subset $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal S$ is indeed a "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$, with respect to the given set of events $\mathcal S$" may be expressed by more explicit notation. I'd prefer: $\mathcal G \equiv \gamma_{\mathcal S}[~A, B~]$.

<sup>2</sup>: Here "arc length" of a given "geodesic path $\mathcal G$" is understood as "[proper arc length](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/167291)" (a "signed quantity"), formally:
$\int_{\mathcal G} \text{sgn}[~\text{ds}^2~]~\sqrt{\text{sgn}[~\text{ds}^2~]~\text{ds}^2} \equiv \int_{\mathcal G} \text{sgn}[~\text{ds}^2~]~\sqrt{~|~\text{ds}^2~|}$,
where the "spacetime interval differential $\text{ds}^2$" [can be positive, zero or negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals).
(This understanding of "arc length" may however be at variance with [the notion "arc length" as described in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Generalization_to_.28pseudo-.29Riemannian_manifolds).)

Therefore the required "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$ of minimal arc length" refers to the (or any) "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$" with the absolutely smallest, possibly negative, arc length of all "geodesic paths between $A$ and $B$", according to a suitable [sign convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention#Relativity). (However, in order to be independent of any particular choice of such a convention, consider the requirement instead as "geodesic path between $A$ and $B$ of extremal arc length, according to any one consistently applied sign convention".)

Comment: Comments: 1. The notation used is unusual, and *geodesics* are more properly phrased as smooth maps $\gamma : [a,b]\to \mathcal{S}$ than subsets of it, although $\gamma([a,b])$ corresponds to what you consider a geodesic. 2. "Minimal arc length" is a difficult term on Lorentzian manifolds (sign issues), you have to define what precisely you mean by it. 3. The properties of $s[A,B]$ to be checked seem rather randomly chosen (though they are most probably not!), why are you interested in them?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "_1. The notation used is unusual [...] $\gamma([a,b])$ corresponds to what you consider a geodesic._" -- "$\gamma([a,b])$" seems to be a stretch (abuse?) of notation: doesn't function $\gamma$ take only one real-number tuple, e.g. $a$, as argument? I'd compromise:$\mathcal G\equiv\gamma_{\mathcal S}[~A,B~]$. "_2. "Min. arc length" is a difficult term_" -- Is "**geodesic** of min. arclength" not definite enough? "_3. Why?_" -- Not least: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162170/why-do-things-slow-down-when-you-move-faster-rather-than-speed-up/162171#comment341211_162171

Comment: @ACuriousMind: p.s., returning to "_2. [...] (sign issues)_" -- In the second ("non-random", "interesting") part of the OP I went to some pains not having to spell out a particular "_sign_", or correspondingly, not to distinguish "_minimal_" from "maximal". Similarly, perhaps I should not necessarily have to ask about "(a) geodesic(s) of minimal arclength", but rather about "(a) geodesic(s) of **extremal** arclength (in a/any consistent sense)".

Comment: 1. For $f: A -> B$, the set of points of B which are images of points of A is very commonly denoted $im(f)$ or $f(A)$. 2. The geodesics are local extrema of the length functional. Due to the sign change, "minimal length" would be a geodesic that is as closest as possible to a null curve, but it is not clear why that should be a good notion (or even exist). Particularly considering [causal structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure), *Mather theory* and other things, it turns (non-trivially) out that the *maximizing* "causal" geodesics are more relevant.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "_1. For f:A->B, the set of points of B which are images of points of A is very commonly denoted im(f) or f(A)._" -- True, but my objection is a bit more subtle: Was I correct to interpret the symbol $a$ (or likewise $b$) in your above comment as one real number **tuple**? If so, what exactly did you mean there by "$[a,b]$"? (Or else? -- go figure.) _2. [...] "minimal length" would be a geodesic that is as closest as possible to a null curve_" -- That's a particularly "Sheldon-esque" hang-up. Meteorologists don't seem to have it when reporting temperature extremes [to be contd.]

Comment: But: of course that's rather an indication of my poor grasp at the appropriate terminology; or, possibly, the present lack of any appropriate terminology to be grasped. "_it turns (non-trivially) out that the maximizing "causal" geodesics are more relevant._" -- Fair enough; but then how to talk about "acausal" (spacelike) geodesics, or best of all how to be "transparent to these issues"?. "_Mather theory and other things_" -- [News to me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubry-Mather_theory) (+1 ?) ...

Comment: Ah, $[a,b]$ is meant to be the *interval* of real numbers between $a$ and $b$ - smooth curves are smooth functions from an interval onto a (smooth) manifold. There are no space-like geodesics because Lorentzian geodesics are locally length maximizing, but you can always find a space-like curve that's longer than a given space-like curve (just take a tube around the given curve and let the longer curve wind around it). (I said "Mather theory and other things" because I know little more than the name myself)

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "_There're no space-like geodesics because [...]_" -- [Wikipedia says otherwise, FWIW: "For a space-like geodesic through two events, there are always nearby curves {of} either a longer or a shorter proper length than the geodesic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Geodesics_as_curves_of_stationary_interval). (And I'm stickin' to it. ;) "_smooth functions from an interval onto a (smooth) manifold._" -- Then "$[a,b]$" is read as some closed "real line interval"; go on to "$\gamma([0, 1])$" and the important specific events $A$, $B$ are hidden from view

Comment: @ACuriousMind Note that geodesics must be stationary "points" of the length functional, not extrema. A spacelike geodesic can very well be a saddle point.